# why bcrypt module can not be installed on windows 8?

Tags: bcrypt

I am using sails js framework for developing an web application and I tried to install bcrypt node module for password hashing. But it is showing the following errors

[image]

is there any solution rather than installing python or VS c++ redistributable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install nodejs build tools for windows.

Maybe this helps.

https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools

Answer (score 2):

What I did was just installed node-bcrypt: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs

It works flawlessly and it's pretty much the same as real bcrypt...

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I removed the caret (^) symbol before the version number in package.json.

Something like this:`"bcrypt": "3.0.0",`